# Module exposing in Elm 0.18

Tags: types, elm

I have an elm module of Types that consists of types and type aliases Foo, Bar and Baz.  When I export everything like so, the code works:

`module Types exposing (..)`

However, if I include all of the types explicitly, the code breaks.

`module Types exposing (Foo, Bar, Baz)`

This is also true of the import statements on the consuming file; both need to be `exposing (..)`

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Could you include examples of how these types are defined. An example of why this could matter is that Union types have a special syntax for including the tags / data constructors.

Comment: @jpierson all of the compiler errors are coming from my attempt to export `Msg`.  I'm trying to export `Msg` like any other type, and defining it as `type Msg = FirstAction | SecondAction | ThirdAction...` and it can't find those actions in my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm only learning Elm myself very recently but it sounds like since one of your types (`Msg`) is being defined as a union type that you will need to use the `Msg(..)` syntax when exporting this type.

```
module Types exposing (Msg (..))

type Msg = FirstAction | SecondAction | ThirdAction
```

Or in the case of *importing* the union type.

```
import Types exposing (Msg (..))
```

Please see GitHub [issue #968](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/968) for an explanation of why this is required for union types.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this type definition:

```
    type Foo
        = Foo
        | Baz
        | Quux
```

You see two `Foo`'s: the previous is **type constructor** and the latter is **data constructor**. Type constructors and data constructors live in different namespaces, so you can use the same name for both.

As you write

```
    import Types exposing (Foo)
```

you are importing **type constructor** `Foo` **only**. To import `Foo`'s data constructors, you have to do it explicitly in parentheses after the import of type constructor:

```
    import Types exposing (Foo (Foo, Baz))
```

or, if you want to import all data constructors of this type:

```
    import Types exposing (Foo (..))
```